# Opencart Floating contact form extension is not working

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart version 1.5.6.I have implemented the [floating contact form extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6677&filter_search=contact%20form&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=32&page=1). I have extracted the file and paste the files of upload folder into my directory.But it is not supporting. I can't get any output in my front end as well as the module is not added in my admin.

Comment: This is not a question suited for StackOverflow (read the help section to find out what kind of questions to ask and what to avoid asking). If You have problem with thrid party extension, always ask for support the extension's developer and if that fails, You can ask for support at OpenCart support team. Lastly You can try OpenCart's forums.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to try:

1. Read the extension documentation and make sure that the files are imported correctly (verify the file paths).
2. Check the file permissions of imported files.
3. If there's vqmod xml file, make sure that you've vqmod installed.
4. Turn on display_errors and debug.
5. Contact extension developer.

Comment: in my opinion you should not answer such type of non programming related question until the user edits the question to make it programming related. this type of question are for opencart forum and not stackoverflow and does not meet stackoverflow quality standards

Comment: You're right, but sometimes I feel like just telling them some ways to fix the issue - instead of telling off-topic or contact extension developer.

Comment: But it's strange that Your answers are mostly only: *Steps to try: check that the file exists...* - I haven't seen Your answers for a programming related questions for a long time now. And SO is about programming related issues. Questions like this above should be solved on a completely different forum and You should help us to make this happen by closing such a question or explaining to the OP that he is asking incorrect questions instead of answering something just to receive some little rep points... Your answer would better fit only for a comment as it does not answer the question at all.

Comment: I know these are not answers, but just some suggestions that may help them. I couldn't find an option to add bullet list comments, that's why I posted it as an answer. The question seems to be off-topic too, but in some cases like this I thought they may not able to provide more information. It's a free extension, therefore they may not get an immediate response. `I haven't seen Your answers for a programming related questions for a long time now.` - http://stackoverflow.com/users/1878050/sankar-v?tab=answers&sort=newest. Have a nice day !!